# Foward list sort method implementation by passing another function as a parameter

Tags: c++, forward-list

I have a token class with parameters are below-

```
private:
    string theText{};
    vector<size_t> theLineNumbers{};
    size_t theFrequency{ 1 };
```

Now i have an other Tokenizer class which has a list of objects of token class

```
private:
list <Token> theTokenList;
```

Now i want to implement the function that sort the list of objects according to the frequency.
I have written the below code but it's not working.

```
void Tokenizer::sortOnFrequecy()const
{
    forward_list<Token> myflist(theTokenList.cbegin(), theTokenList.cend());
    /*forward_list <Token>::const_iterator it = myflist.cbegin();*/
    sort(myflist.cbegin(), myflist.cend(),compareFrequency());
}

bool Tokenizer::compareFrequency(const Token& t1, const Token& t2)
{
    return (t1.getFrequency() < t2.getFrequency());
}
```

I want to print the list of token, sorted according to the frequency in decreasing order.

Please help me to solve this problem.
Incase any other code is need, then i am more than happy to provide the same.

Comment: Two things: First is that you ***call*** the `compareFrequency` function, no passing a pointer to it. The second is that it needs to be a **`static`** member function, otherwise it can't be called without an object. MY suggestion: Skip the function and use a [*lambda*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) expression.

Comment: [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) requires random access iterators. [`std::forward_list::iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) is a forward iterator, not a random access iterator, so you can't pass it into `std::sort`. [`std::forward_list::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/sort) exists, but even then, you discard the sort. You can directly call [`std::list::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort), or just create the copy in a `std::vector` (or just use `std::vector` to begin with).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this:

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/

You can either make the `compareFrequency` static or move it out of the object entirely. Also you are calling this comparison without any arguments, that does not make sense.

Making the `compareFrequency` a normal function declared outside the object, sorting the list would be just

```c
myflist.sort(compareFrequency);
```